# If statement working..? or not?

Tags: javascript

My display wining message won't display, when the if statement requirements are met

```
//start check function
function check(){

    if(box1 >= 1 && box1 <= 6 && box2 >= 1 && box2 <= 6 && box3 >= 1 && box3 <= 6) 
    {
            //display wining message
            document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Congrats! You win 1 credit.';

            //add one credit when you get 3 reds
            creditCounter = creditCounter + 1;
    }
    if(box1 >= 7 && box1 <= 9 && box2 >= 7 && box2 <= 9 && box3 >= 7 && box3 <= 9) 
    {       
            //display wining message
            document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Congrats! You win 10 credit.';

            //add 10 credits when you get 3 green
            creditCounter = creditCounter + 10;
    }
    if(box1 == 10 && box2 == 10 && box3 == 10) 
    {
            //display wining message
            document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Congrats! You win 100 credit.';    

            //add 100 credits when you get 3 blue
            creditCounter = creditCounter + 100;
    }
    else{
           //display losing message
           document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Sorry, please try again.';
    }
}//END check() function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is my if statment working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170621/is-my-if-statment-working)

Comment: *Something* has to display due to your `else` block. If the text isn't displaying, you have an error in your code.

Comment: do you have an error in the console ?

Comment: no errors on error console, and what else has to be in my else block?

Comment: After each check, for instance where you add the creditCounter you want to `return` to stop it going through the rest of the checks.. as at the moment if the last criteria isnt met then it will display "try again" even if the others were met

Comment: Where are you setting the `box1`, `box2`, etc variables?

Comment: it worked thank you, but the credits won, arent being added.

Comment: setting the box variables in another function.

Comment: its a div element with an id called header.

Comment: is `creditCounter` already set globally?

Comment: @user2832137 if you meant my comment worked - please check my answer below to make sure you've set the `return` in the right place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the checks once the criteria has been met, do this with a `return`.. for instance:

```
//start check function
function check(){

    if(box1 >= 1 && box1 <= 6 && box2 >= 1 && box2 <= 6 && box3 >= 1 && box3 <= 6) 
    {
        //display wining message
        document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Congrats! You win 1 credit.';

        //add one credit when you get 3 reds
        creditCounter = creditCounter + 1;

        return; // they won 1 credit.. finish checking
    }
    if(box1 >= 7 && box1 <= 9 && box2 >= 7 && box2 <= 9 && box3 >= 7 && box3 <= 9) 
    {       
        //display wining message
        document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Congrats! You win 10 credit.';

        //add 10 credits when you get 3 green
        creditCounter = creditCounter + 10;

        return; // they won 10 credits.. finish checking
    }
    if(box1 == 10 && box2 == 10 && box3 == 10) 
    {
        //display wining message
        document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Congrats! You win 100 credit.';    

        //add 100 credits when you get 3 blue
        creditCounter = creditCounter + 100;
    }
    else{
       //display losing message
       document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'Sorry, please try again.';
    }
}//END check() function
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing "else if", so for the case if winning conditions are met, the last "else" will be proceed anyway.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E9CMA/2/

```
if(box1 >= 1 && box1 <= 6 && box2 >= 1 && box2 <= 6 && box3 >= 1 && box3 <= 6) 
{
...
}

else if(box1 >= 7 && box1 <= 9 && box2 >= 7 && box2 <= 9 && box3 >= 7 && box3 <= 9) 
{       
...
}

else if(box1 == 10 && box2 == 10 && box3 == 10) 
{
...
}
else{
...
}
```